# Insert into table, in 2 phases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: table1 and table2 (The tables are almost identical, table2 has an extra field. 30 columns in table1, and 31 columns in table2. the extra column is a key).
I also have a procedure, which gets a number at first. If the number is above 10, I want to isnert the row in all the 30 columns from table1 to table2. Otherwise, I want to insert columns 1 to 20 (from table1), and insert columns 20-30 multiplied by 30. I have created two different "INSERT INTO TABLE" for each situation (above/under 10), but I belive there is more efficient way, since the first 20 rows should be the same in every case.  I thought to insert first the first 20 rows, and after enter "IF" statement and then 'insert' according to the given parameter the remain columns. But ofcourse I'm getting two rows instead of one.

what is the solution, so I will insert all the data into one row?

Here is an example with 10 columns (instead of 30). In this example, if the paramter is above 10, we'll insert the row as is into *table2*. otherwise, we will insert col1-col7, and multiply col8-col10.
**parameter = 15**

**table1**

```
 Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | Col8 | Col9 |Col10 | 
======+======+======+======+======+======+======+======+======+======+
  1   |   1  |  1   |   2  |   2  |   2  |   2  |  5   |   5  |   5  |
```

**table2**   (Identical to table 1, because the parameter > 10 )

```
 Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | Col8 | Col9 |Col10 | 
======+======+======+======+======+======+======+======+======+======+
  1   |   1  |  1   |   2  |   2  |   2  |   2  |  5   |   5  |   5  |
```

If the parameter was **parameter = 3** , then table two was:

**table2**   (columns 8-10 multiplied)

```
 Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | Col8 | Col9 |Col10 | 
======+======+======+======+======+======+======+======+======+======+
  1   |   1  |  1   |   2  |   2  |   2  |   2  | 150  | 150  | 150  |  



A template to my code:  

if @Parameter >10  
begin  
        INSERT INTO Table1  
               (Col1  
               ,Col2  
               ,Col3  
                ...
               ,Col29  
               ,Col30)  

        SELECT  
                Col1  
               ,Col2  
               ,Col3  
                ...
               ,Col29  
               ,Col30  
       FROM ...
       wHERE ...  
end  
else  
begin  


  INSERT INTO Table1  
             (Col1  
             ,Col2  
             ,Col3  
              ...
             ,Col29  
             ,Col30)  

      SELECT  
              Col1  
             ,Col2  
             ,Col3  
              ...
             ,Col29  
             ,Col30  
     FROM ...
     wHERE ...  

 end
```

Right now I have more then 120 lines, when 2/3 from them are duplicated.
 How can I make it more efficient?

Comment: Can you create a variable, and set it to 1 or 30, based on your input parameter.  Then have the last columns be multiplied by that variable.

Comment: Post your "inefficient" code  please.

Comment: Posted the code @PaulSpiegel

Comment: I'm not familiar with sql-server - But you could first INSERT all columns, and then do an UPDATE on inserted rows if @Parameter <=10

Answer (score -1):

As far as I could your problem you could use,INSERT ALL COMMAND

FOR eg:-

INSERT ALL
WHEN number>10 THEN
INTO table1 VALUES(col1,col2,col3)
INTO table1 VALUES(col1,col2,col3)
WHEN number<10
INTO table1 VALUES(col1,col2,col3)
INTO table1 VALUES(col1,col2,col3)
select * from dual

use condition as per your requirement